# (Data.Monoid) - Sum and Product deriving Bounded and Num at the same time?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monoids, deriving

in [`Data.Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Semigroup.Internal.html#Sum) :

```
newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }
    deriving ( Eq       -- ^ @since 2.01
             , Ord      -- ^ @since 2.01
             , Read     -- ^ @since 2.01
             , Show     -- ^ @since 2.01
             , Bounded  -- ^ @since 2.01
             , Generic  -- ^ @since 4.7.0.0
             , Generic1 -- ^ @since 4.7.0.0
             , Num      -- ^ @since 4.7.0.0
             )
```

I don't understand how you could derive `Num` and `Bounded` on `Sum` with `Integer`, `Float` etc... which are naturally not `Bounded` (it's the same story for the `Product` wrapper).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this makes `Sum a` an instance of (say) `Eq` whenever `a` is an instance of `Eq`.

```
instance (Eq a) => Eq (Sum a) where ...
```

And likewise for all the other classes.

Comment: Indeed; `:info Sum` explicitly shows `instance Eq a => Eq (Sum a)`.